# Trying to debug a PWM motor drive with cascode configuration - is the MOSFET busted?

Tags: mosfet, pwm, bjt, opto-isolator, cascode

I made a simple DC/universal motor drive as per the circuit in the picture. I was experimenting with it by powering it from a variable transformer. Note that both Vdd (300V) and the 12V Vb1 (for biasing the BJT) are obtained from the same rectified and filtered source, so as I increase the voltage on the variable transformer, both of these increase proportionately.
[image: Schematic of motor drive]

This was working fine, until last Friday: as I was winding down the voltage on the variable transformer to close to 0, I pulled the motor drive plug from it, heard a pop accompanied by what I think was a spark or other kind of brief light. I don't know where on the board the light/spark came from. I am partially visually impaired (long story).

The situation now is that the motor will spin even without a PWM signal. As I start increasing the voltage of the variac, it will start spinning suddenly as i reach about ~80V AC (translates into about ~100V DC).

Desoldering the MOSFET right now is not possible for me. But I embarked on a quest to troubleshoot/debug my board. I measured the following voltages while gradually increasing the variac voltage: Vgs, Vds, Vce(optocoupler). See the picture with the voltage diagram. As you can see, as I reach a certain threshold voltage, the MOSFET starts conducting (and hence the bipolar transistor also). At this point Vgs goes from 0 to 10 mV. Vds increases gradually until this threshold and then jumps from 1V to 2V, but soon after it retreats to about 1.8V and stays there. The voltage across the optocouplers phototransistor keeps gradually increasing, so I assume the optocoupler is not busted.
[image: Voltages measured as Vvariac is increased]

Do you think I am right to assume that the MOSFET is dead? If yes, can you tell me how I could protect it from surges, to avoid the problem I had when I pulled the cord from the variac?

Comment: Where is the CMOS circuitry on your schematic? Why are you using a cascode driver instead of a MOSFET on its own?

Comment: Vb1 ~= Vceopto. So how can Vds = 2V when Vceopto is less than 2V? If Q2 is working correctly then Vds should be ~0.6V below Vb1 (assuming negligible voltage drop across R1).

Comment: `I pulled the motor drive plug from it` ... this is not a clear description of what you did

Comment: So, this motor drive is powered from mains - it has an AC power plug that plugs into the mains. Here in Germany this is a Schuko type plug - specifically a CEE 7/3 type. In my case it plugs into the variac (variable transformer). 

Let me know if this clarifies the issue.

Comment: @BruceAbbott You are right that Vb1 is approximately equal to Vceopto.
`So how can Vds = 2V when Vceopto is less than 2V?`
That's a very good question. I assume I just didn't draw the diagram carefully enough. I could go back to the lab to check the exact Vceopto at threshold. 
`assuming negligible voltage drop across R1`
Did you really mean R1? R1 is not on the drive side, it's in series with the optocoupler's LED.

Comment: @BruceAbbott I went back and measured Vceopto more carefully. It turns out it's 2.61V at threshold and then it retreats to 2.48V.
I could try to redraw the diagram. I am not sure I can add an edited diagram to my question, but let me try.

Comment: Set your DMM to diode mode and measure the Vf of the body-diode of the MOSFET and report back.

Comment: Your removal of the question is hardly in the spirit of the site and a bit rude to those who gave of their time. The question is still visible to users with enough rep in the edit history anyway. -1.

Comment: I'm voting to close this posting as off-topic because it does not contain any question.

Comment: @Transistor   I am trying to streamline the content of this wonderful and useful website by removing posts that are clearly of no use to the community (see current rating and lack of answers).

I am just trying to help by not introducing noise in the discussion. I am sad I could not completely eradicate my own post.

Comment: It is very telling that the only useful comment was by @BruceAbbot who got no upvotes except mine. That was a slight motive for me to remove this post. It attracted low quality comments except his, and yet his comment was not even upvoted (except for me).

Comment: @SuperMarioBro  There's a possibility that it will be of interest in the future to someone.  So, I disagree with "of no use to the community".  Notice also that most of the downvoting took place *after* you have tried to edit-destroy your post.

Answer (score 1):

As I suspected from the voltage measurements, the MOSFET is indeed broken. This was confirmed when a colleague desoldered it from the circuit. Measuring gate-to-source resistance resulted in about 30 ohm, either direction. Drain-to-source resistance is ~100 ohm at 1 mA and it is very non-linear (decreases with current).

A snubber circuit will be added to the design to avoid the problem from occurring again.

Comment: For the future, resistance measurement of MOSFETs is not always reliable. 99 % of the time it gives you the correct results but you will learn the hard way one day. Set your DMM to diode measurement and measure the Vf of the body diode.